# Javascript - Local storage - Remove item doesn't work

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I set an item in localstorage in this way:

```
localStorage.setItem("test", "testing");
```

Now, I try to remove it but it's not working. I found and tried the following solutions without any result:

```
localStorage.removeItem("test");
localStorage.removeItem(0);
window.localStorage.removeItem(0);
window.localStorage.removeItem("test");
```

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: How are you verifying that it doesn't work?

Comment: The APIs you're using are correct. Like @Phil said how are you verifying this? Are you opening the developer console and checking there?

Comment: @Phil, @Darkrum  I'm checking with this : `var test_value = localStorage.getItem("test");` Then : `console.log(test_value);`

Comment: @MArbez do you do that before or after removing the item? The value returned by `localStorage.getItem` is a string and thus, immutable. It is **not** an object reference if that's what you were expecting

Comment: Ok, your example is working. Now, I'm trying on an array stored as JSON (this was the final goal of my question).

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. It wasn't local storage, it was due to the order of executions of my functions.
In my first function, I set the local storage variable.
In the second one, I use it and remove it.

The problem was that the second function was executed faster than the first one. So the data was deleted and then, set again. That gave me the impression that local storage deletion wasn't working.

Comment: Sometimes it happens when for some mistake you try to remove it from sessionStorage instead localStorage where it remains. The removeItem don't throw an exception if it fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem. It wasn't local storage, it was due to the order of executions of my functions. 
In my first function, I set the local storage variable. In the second one, I use it and remove it. 
The problem was that the second function was executed faster than the first one. So the data was deleted and then, set again. That gave me the impression that local storage deletion wasn't working.

Comment: Helpful direction in looking for the error. Glad you persisted to find the answer and update the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be caused by your local hosting

this problem happened to me and I always thought that the problem was from my code, but later it became clear to me that the problem is from the **local hosting**

I used this address in my project:

```
http://192.168.1.10:8080
```

And then I replaced the address with this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

The problem is solved and now I can delete all LocalStorage from the inspect.